# Why intuitively do the eigenvalues of the Casimir operators classify irreps?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, invariants

Distinguishing between distinct unitary irreducible representations is important from the point of view of distinguishing between different sorts of particles; the eigenvalues of the Casimir operators provide a way of doing this.

I have never properly understood why this is the case. Is there a good way of seeing why any two distinct irreps must, necessarily, have different eigenvalues for at least one Casimir?

Comment: I wouldn't count on this being true for infinite-dimensional representations.

Comment: This is interesting to me because I have been reading papers that make use of the casimirs of the infinite dimensional irreps of the little group for massless particles in a pretty central way. I asked this question precisely because it seemed not obvious why it would work for infinite dimensions!

Comment: But in any case my intuition about the finite dimensional case is also lacking so I would be content with an explanation of that and that only I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The fact that a Casimir operator/invariant takes a single eigenvalue on an entire (finite-dimensional) [irrep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation) (over $\mathbb{C}$) follows from [Schur's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma).
2. It is also clear that a Casimir takes the same eigenvalue on [equivalent](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Equivalent_representations) (=isomorphic) irreps.
3. So OP's question essentially boils down to whether there are enough Casimirs to distinguish different irreps (modulo equivalence). That is the topic of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64929/2451) related Phys.SE post.