# Quadratic Casimir operator of higher dimensional $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ representations

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, representation-theory, invariants

In higher dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{su(3)}$, what will be the quadratic Casimir operator? Is it same as in lower dimensions or different?

Comment: What do you mean by "the same"? Different representations act on different spaces, and there is no (obvious) notion of equality for operators acting on different spaces.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63394/2451 More on Casimir operators: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+Casimir+operator

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you have not asked what you wanted to. The ***operator form***
of all Casimir operators is the same as lionelbrits points out, and SU(3) has *two independent ones*, unlike SU(2), which only has one, the quadratic one. The two are a quadratic and a cubic, included here for completeness.

However, the ***eigenvalues*** of these operators vary with (irreducible) representation, and, in fact, serve to distinguish among them and label/characterize them cf. [Pais (1966)](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.38.215).

All states in a given irreducible representation assume the same value for each Casimir operator, which serves as the identity in a space with the dimension of that representation. This  is because states in a given representation are connected by the action of the generators of the Lie algebra, and all generators commute with the Casimir operators.

For SU(3), the quadratic Casimir is $\hat{C_2}=\sum_k   \hat{F_k}   \hat{F_k}$, and the cubic one is $ \hat{C_3}=\sum_{jkl}d_{jkl}    \hat{F_j} \hat{F_k} \hat{F_l}$. The F̂s are the 8 normalized generators of this Lie algebra.

The irreducible representations of SU(3) are denoted in the Dynkin basis by  $D(p,q)$, consisting of $p$ quarks and $q$ antiquarks (in Young tableaux,  $p$  is the number of single-box columns and $q$ the number of double-box columns): they have  dimension $d(p,q)=\frac{1}{2}(p+1)(q+1)(p+q+2)$.

For example, for the triplet representation,  $D(1,0)$, the eigenvalue of  $\hat{C}_2$ is 4/3, and of $\hat{C}_3$, 10/9.

More generally,  for generic irrep  $D(p,q)$, the eigenvalue of $\hat{C}_2$  is $(p^2+q^2+3p+3q+pq)/3$, which I suspect was what you were *really* asking, above.

N.B. An aside, strictly speaking: The eigenvalue ("anomaly coefficient") of the cubic one, $\hat{C}_3$, is$(p-q)(3+p+2q)(3+q+2p)/18$, an odd function under the interchange *p↔q*. Consequently, it  vanishes for real representations, *p=q*, such as the adjoint, $D(1,1)$, i.e. both this cubic Casimir and anomalies vanish for the octet, the **27**, the **64**, etc..

Comment: How can I compute the quadratic Casimir for $u(n)$ and $u(m|n)$ (unitary Lie and superLie algebras)? How can I label highest-weight states of these algebras?

Comment: @QGravity : Straightforward, but long answer: Hall, Brian C. (2015), Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 222 (2nd ed.), Springer, ISBN 978-3319134666

Comment: Wouldn't the eigenvalue of $\hat{C}_2$ for $\rm SU(3)$ be $(p^2+q^2+3p+3q+pq)/3$?

Comment: @Urb , sure, thanks!, fixed; undetected all these years!.....

Answer (score 0):

The algebraic form of the quadratic casimir $T^2$ depends only on the structure constants, and are therefore the same in any representation. As in $SU(2)$, of course, it's matrix form is representation dependent.

Edit:
To see why this is the case, suppose you constructed $T^2$ out of other elements of the algebra, and you did this for say, the fundamental representation. You then had to show that $\left[T^2, T_i\right]=0$ for all $T_i$. Of course, you can only use the structure constants, i.e., $[T_i, T_j] = i f_{ijk} T_k$ and $\{T_i, T_j\} = \frac{1}{N} \delta_{ij} + d_{ijk} T_k$ to show this. But these don't depend on the representation. They are what define the algebra, i.e., what make it $\mathfrak{su}(N)$.

Comment: can you suggest me any material for proof of what you have said " The algebraic form of the quadratic T2 casimir  depends only on the structure constants, and are therefore the same in any representation"

Comment: Ummm the Lie algebra does not depend on the representation, but the [anticommutator does](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221851/the-anticommutator-of-sun-generators)... In fact, the anticommutator expression you wrote *only* holds for the fundamental.