# Quadratic Casimir operator of $SU(3)$ in a general irreduccible representation

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, representation-theory

1. Which is the general representation $(n,m)$ of $SU(3)$ and how can I prove that $$C_{2}^{su(3)} = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}(n^2+m^2+n\cdot m)+n\cdot m\right)\delta_{ij}~? $$
2. and the other question is why we need to define the cubic Casimir operator for $SU(3)$.

I know that the usual way is to use the basis $$\lbrace{T_{3},T_{8},F^{2}_{1},F_{2}^{1},F_{1}^{3},F_{3}^{1},F_{2}^{3},F_{3}^{2}\rbrace} $$

and then remembering that $$C_{2} = g^{ij}e_{i}e_{j}\Rightarrow C_{2}^{su(3)} = \frac{1}{3}\left(T_{3}^{2}+T_{2}^{2}+F_{1}^{2}F_{2}^{1}+F_{2}^{1}F_{1}^{2}+F_{1}^{3}F_{3}^{1}+F_{3}^{1}F^{1}_{3}+F_{2}^{3}F_{3}^{2}+F_{3}^{2}F_{2}^{3}\right) $$

but I can't see how to get the first expression. In $SU(2)$ we used its complex extension $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$ defining the new basis $$\lbrace{T_{+},T_{-},T_{3}\rbrace} $$

where $T_{i}=ie_{i}$ and $T_{\pm} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_{i}\pm ie_{i})$ and working a bit we can find that $$C_{2}^{su(2)} = \frac{1}{2}(T_{+}T_{-}+T_{-}T_{+}+T_{3}^{2}) $$ and using the eigenvalues of the basis elements we finally prove that $$C_{2}^{su(2)}|j>= \frac{1}{2}m(m+1)|j> $$ I think that it's something analogous maybe? the pdf's that I've been reading on internet are so unclear :(

Any help is very grateful!

Comment: 1. Always explain your notation! How exactly are you labelling a $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ representation by two numbers $(n,m)$? (I can guess it, but it should be written out) 2. What is your definition of "Casimir operator" here (i.e. what is the l.h.s. of the equation you want to prove defined as)?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sorry! but that's my question, I don't understand what is the $(n,m)$ general representation. I've been reading and I found that there are the weight vectors, if you can edit my question giving the definition would be great! (sorry but really in my class notes I don't have more definitions, that part of the course wasn't good explain). Btw, my Casimir operator definition is $g^{ij}e_{i}e_{j}$, where $g$ is the Cartan's metric tensor, i.e., $g_{ij}=f_{il}^{k}f_{jk}^{l}$, where $f_{il}^{k}$ are the structure constant of the algebra, for $SU(2)$ is $g_{ij}=-2\delta_{ij}$ for example

Comment: Well...in that case you can't really "prove" what you want to prove. I suspect that you have a similar formula for the cubic Casimir somewhere, yes? In that case, $n$ and $m$ might be simply *defined* by those two formulae (solving the two equations for the eigenvalues of the Casimirs will yield unique $n,m$), so there's little to prove.

Comment: Yes, my cubic Casimir definition is $C_{3}^{su(3)} = -id_{ijk}T_{i}T_{j}T_{k}$ where $d_{ijk} = \frac{1}{4}Tr\lbrace (\lambda_{i}\lambda_{j}+\lambda_{j}\lambda_{i})\lambda_{k}\rbrace$, $\lambda_{i}$ Gell-Mann matrices (sorry I have a lot of definitions). Btw thanks! I'll try it and I'll keep reading

Comment: You know, you are asking for a mini-course. Start from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Casimir_operators), and move on to Hall's book, or Iachello, or... or...  The Dynkin (n,m) notation means n quarks and m antiquarks: n single columns and 2 double columns in the young tableau. You have as many independent Casimirs as the rank, here 2. You cannot get a needed minicourse in a PSE answer. Might as well hit the books.

Comment: [R Cahn](http://phyweb.lbl.gov/~rncahn/www/liealgebras/texall.pdf) & [F Iachello](https://books.google.com/books?id=H03PBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA266&lpg=PA266&dq=iachello+group+theory+book&source=bl&ots=p6jBf1AGsf&sig=An-a_KpZALif658Qrezvx6vjgxg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4i-GEleDQAhUqLZoKHZeYCiwQ6AEIMjAF#v=onepage&q=%207.2.2&f=false).

Comment: Very related question [150481](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150481/quadratic-casimir-operator-of-higher-dimensional-mathfraksu3-representati).

Answer (score 3):

Take your expression for $C^2$ in terms of operators and re-express your operators in terms of raising and lowering operators, then act with your new expression for $C^2$ on the highest weight state.  The raising operators will kill the state, or if they appear on the left you can commute the raising operators to the right so they kill the highest weight state.  You will be left with diagonal operators, from which you may easily extract the eigenvalue (which is non-trivial).  Basically I'm saying in words to repeat the procedure for SU(2), i.e. indeed go to the complex entension.

In general irreps of $su(3)$ are labelled by two non-negative integers ($m$ and $n$ in your case).  For the irrep $(m,n)$, the highest weight is $m w_1+n w_2$, where $w_1$ and $w_2$ are the fundamental weights.  The benefit of this notation is that it *uniquely* identifies the irrep, as opposed to using the dimension as a label (which is not unique).

As to why we need to define a cubic Casimir for SU(3): we don't "need" to define it; it is a statement of fact that there is such an invariant operator.  It's use is not so common because we rarely have observables that are cubic in the generators, but its eigenvalue is used as additional label when the eigenvalue of $C^2$ is degenerate or not enough for labelling purposes.