# Bosonic representation of $SU(N)$: what values can $n_b$ take?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, group-theory, lie-algebra

In Assa Auerbach's book on page 166, he describes the construction of a bosonic representation of $SU(N)$ where the generators $S^{mn} \rightarrow b^\dagger_m b_n$. I'm a bit confused about the constraint in cases $N\ne 2$:

$$ n_b= \sum_{n}^N b^\dagger_n b_n = NS $$

where $S$ is the spin representation and $n_b$ is the total number of bosons representing that spin. Clearly, in $SU(2)$, $S$ takes on positive integer and half integer values, so that $NS = (0, 1,2 ...)$.

What about in $N>2$? Wikipedia shows that the adjoint irrep of $SU(3)$ has $16/3$ which is not a half integer. Basically I'm asking what the allowed values of $S$ are for a given $N$, and how to work this out?

Comment: What is the meaning of $16/3$?  Is it a Casimir eigenvalue?

Comment: Yes it's a sum over the square of all 8 generators

Comment: ? The quadratic Casimir for SU(3)  is 4/3 for the triplet, 3 for the adjoint (octet), [etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Casimir_operators). What, exactly, are you insinuating?

Comment: [Related Casimir formulas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150481/quadratic-casimir-operator-of-higher-dimensional-mathfraksu3-representati).

Comment: Which Wikipedia page?

Comment: The number operator for bosons has eignevalues 0,1,2,3 ... You probably want to identify each with a specific representation for SU(3) characterized by its Casimir, just as you actually determined S from $n_b/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jordan's (1935) [nifty map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map) is a Lie algebra isomorphism of generator matrices (and the vectors they act on) to Fock bilinears (and the Fock states they operate on). It expedites some representation theory, as Schwinger illustrated on SU(2) — after a hiatus of 17 years.

As you presumably already saw, for SU(2), 
$$
{\vec  J} \equiv    {\mathbf  a}^\dagger \cdot\frac{ {\vec  \sigma } } {2} \cdot    {\mathbf a}^{\,}   ~, \qquad  n  \equiv \sum_{i=1}^2 a^\dagger_i a^{\,}_i   \equiv    {\mathbf  a}^\dagger \cdot    {\mathbf a}^{\,}   ~ ,
$$ 
so the quadratic Casimir operator is 
$$
{\vec  J} \cdot {\vec  J} = \frac{n}{2} \left ( \frac{n}{2}+1\right )~. $$

You may thus identify *n* with *2j*, and count aggregate modes, whose net number the *J*s cannot change. They automatically separate (reduce) the subspaces characterized by a given common *j=n/2*. That is, they connect only states $a_1^{\dagger ~ k} a_2^{\dagger ~ l}|0\rangle$ among themselves, sharing a common $k+l=n=2j$. You may call this "projection" if you focus on  a *j* of interest to you.

On to SU(3), now with three fundamental oscillators, so their dot products range over indices from 1 to 3 (*N* for general SU(*N*)). The conventionally normalized generators are the eight 
$$
 F_a \equiv    {\mathbf  a}^\dagger \cdot\frac{ {  \lambda_a } } {2} \cdot    {\mathbf a} ~,
$$
where the $\lambda_a$ s are the [Gell—Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices#Fierz_completeness_relations), obeying the Fierz identity where 
$$\lambda^{a ~~i} _j   \lambda^{a~~k} _l   = 2 \delta^i_l  \delta^k _l  -\frac{2}{3}  \delta^i_j  \delta^k _l    ~.
$$

The quadratic Casimir then evaluates to (Einstein summation convention over repeated indices!)
$$
 {\mathbf  a}^\dagger \cdot\frac{ {  \lambda_a } } {2} \cdot    {\mathbf a}~~~ {\mathbf  a}^\dagger \cdot\frac{ {  \lambda_a } } {2} \cdot    {\mathbf a}=-\frac{1}{6}  {\mathbf  a}^\dagger      \cdot    {\mathbf a}~~{\mathbf  a}^\dagger      \cdot    {\mathbf a}+\frac{1}{2}a_i^\dagger a_k a^\dagger_k a_i \\
=\frac{1}{3} n(n+3)~.
$$

You may recognize this as the quadratic Casimir $(p+3p)/3$ of *p* symmetrized quarks' representation, *D(p,0)*, so *n* is quark number,   without any antiquarks—no columns in the respective Young tableau. The dimension *d(p,0)* of these representations is *(p+1)(p+2)/2* ; hence *p=1* for the fundamental triplet, with Casimir eignevalue 4/3. (Your 16/3 is for Gell—Mann matrix bilinears, which are here normalized by a 2 each, to become SU(3) generators.)

To reassure yourself, inspect states for *p=2*, so *d=3*, so *C=10/3*. Further, *p=3*, so *d=10*, so *C=6*, etc.

NB The adjoint, *D(1,1)* is not in this symmetrized collection--it has an antiquark as well, hence the telltale Γ Young tableau.

For basics of the direct SU(*N*) generalization, see Iachello, or Greiner-Mueller ...

Comment: So then the number of bosons can still take any integer $n_b = (0,1,2,3..)$ in $SU(N)$ given the proper representation? I've seen papers varying $n_b$ and $N$ independently (e.g. looking at limits where one or the other is sent to infinity, or they are both sent to infinity with $n_b/M$ held fixed), and this is the origin of my question-- (1) is this valid (are they actually independent)? and (2) then this process is actually taking limits on the representation of SU(N)? I can provide an example paper if it helps to answer my question

Comment: Yes. $n_b$ can take arbitrary integral values and characterizes a rep... albeit not uniquely (which did not come up here.... that's why you use more, higher,  Casimirs). *N* characterizes a group. The two are conceptually independent. What is *M*?

Comment: sorry typo, M=N -- the paper uses M and I am going back and forth between notation!